# CosmosDB Gremlin: Resource with specified id or name already exists

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, databricks

I would like to [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIARm.jpg) create a graph using gremlin API in cosmosDB. I'm getting data from a pyspark dataframe in databricks.

I have several id's with filenames. The filenames are different although the id's can be same. I would like to have a vertex with id and then if the id is same and filename is different then again a vertex under the first and so on.

a snippet for the code

```
if cNum not in gremlinQuery("g.V().id()"):
    gremlinQuery(
             "g.addV('Number').property('id', '{}').property('filename', '{}').property('filepath', '{}').property('date', '{}').addV('filenam').property('filen', '{}').property('date', '{}').addE('old').to(g.V('{}'))".format(cNum,filen,fpath,date,filen,fpath,date,cName))   

  elif cNum in gremlinQuery("g.V().id()"): 
       if filen not in gremlinQuery("g.V().properties('filename').value()"):
        gremlinQuery(
             "g.addV('Number').property('cNumber', '{}').property('filename', '{}').property('filepath', '{}').property('date', '{}').addV('filenam').property('filen', '{}').property('date', '{}').addE('old').to(g.V('{}'))".format(cNum,filen,fpath,date,filen,fpath,date,cName))

if date in gremlinQuery("g.V().hasLabel('Number').values('date')"):
          gremlinQuery("g.".format(filen,cName,date,cNum))

elif date not in gremlinQuery("g.V().hasLabel('Number').values('date')"):
        gremlinQuery("g.addV('cmmName').property('Name', '{}').property('filen', '{}').property('date', '{}').addE('new').to(g.V('{}'))".format(cName,filen,date,cNum))
```